# How to send data from activity to a webview in that activity itself?

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

**From this Activity I am sending data to another activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final EditText etxt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            final EditText etxt1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String s= etxt.getText().toString();
                            String s1= etxt1.getText().toString();
            Intent intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),WebActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("key", s);
                            intent.putExtra("key1", s1);
        }
    });
}
}
```

**My second activity where i receive the data from intent and want to display it in the webview.**

```
public class WebActivity extends Activity {
WebView webView;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webpage);
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String s = b.getString("key");
            String s1=b.getString("key1");
    webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);

}
```

}

From some searching on Google i found that it can be accomplished by using javascript variables but I dont know how to do it. Kindly answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you checked Android [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) documentation?

```
 // Simplest usage: note that an exception will NOT be thrown
 // if there is an error loading this page (see below).
 webview.loadUrl("http://slashdot.org/");

 // OR, you can also load from an HTML string:
 String summary = "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body></html>";
 webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);
 // ... although note that there are restrictions on what this HTML can do.
 // See the JavaDocs for loadData() and loadDataWithBaseURL() for more info.
```

Comment: Suppose, i want to send json data to webview then?

Comment: String summary = "<html><body>YOUR JSON HERE</body></html>";
webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add your data in webview by

```
webview.loadData("your string text", "text/html", null);
```